# Error and confusion when creating datatype and monad

Tags: haskell

Consider the next piece of code:

```
data Tile   = EmptyTile | X | O
data Player = Player1 | Player2

instance Show Tile where
    show EmptyTile = " "
    show X         = "X"
    show O         = "O"

data Board = (Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile)

emptyBoard :: Board
emptyBoard = (EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile)

instance Monad Board where
    return x = x
    f >>= x = x
```

I'd like that Board will be a monad. But the problem is that i get the following error -

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )

Main.hs:17:14: error:
    Illegal binding of built-in syntax: (,,,,,,,,)
```

What needs to be changed so that Board can be defined later on as a monad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every `data` constructor must have an unambiguous name, such as you gave with `EmptyTile`, `X`, `O`, `Player1` and `Player2`. With `Board`, there is no such name; Haskell desugars this as

```
data Board = (,,,,,,,,) Tile Tile Tile Tile Tile Tile Tile Tile Tile
```

so here, `(,,,,,,,,)` would be the “constructor name”, but that's not actually legal in Haskell, thus the error.

Just choose a custom name, like boring

```
data Board = Board Tile Tile Tile Tile Tile Tile Tile Tile Tile
```

Now, this cannot possibly be a monad: a monad is foremostly a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor), i.e. something that's parameterised on some type and covariant in that parameter. You can make it a monad though, by replacing those hard-coded `Tile` fields with something polymorphic:

```
data Board t = Board t t t t t t t t t
    deriving (Functor)
```

But the `Applicative` and `Monad` instances will look a bit more involved than what you proposed.

You might consider an approach like this: instead of hand-rolling the `Board` data structure, you define an *indexing type*:

```
data BoardIndex = Edge0 | Middle | Edge1
type Board t = (BoardIndex, BoardIndex) -> t
```

Then this will be a monad without any further definitions, namely the *function monad*, which has the semantics you probably want here. It tends to be a bit inefficient since results aren't actually *stored* but always recomputed on the spot, but for something like Tic Tac Toe that will hardly matter. (You can easily make it more efficient later, by introducing [memoisation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.8/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html).)

Answer (score 4):

You write `data` but mean `type` or `newtype`:

```
data Tile   = EmptyTile | X | O
data Player = Player1 | Player2

instance Show Tile where
    show EmptyTile = " "
    show X         = "X"
    show O         = "O"

type Board = (Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile)

emptyBoard :: Board
emptyBoard = (EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile)
-- this won’t work
instance Monad Board where
    return x = x
    f >>= x = x
```

Or

```
data Tile   = EmptyTile | X | O
data Player = Player1 | Player2

instance Show Tile where
    show EmptyTile = " "
    show X         = "X"
    show O         = "O"

newtype Board = Board (Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile)

emptyBoard :: Board
emptyBoard = Board (EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile,EmptyTile)
-- this also won’t work 
instance Monad Board where
    return x = x
    f >>= x = x
```

It’s also worth noting that a board in a game of tic tax toe isn’t going to be a `Monad`. For one thing it would need a type parameter and for another thing it will obviously never satisfy the laws.